# How to change TBitBtn back color?

Tags: delphi

I need to **change `TBitBtn`'s back color**. Please suggest me the way to change it.

Comment: TBitBtn is a windows common control wrapper. Windows has decided that this window class can't change its color.  Find a custom delphi button control that does what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

You might replace your BitButton to another button component that implements this property.

One simple and quick solution is to replace each of your BitButton with a pair SpeedButton/Panel. Set SpeedButton's Flat property to False; set Panel's BevelInner and BevelOuter to None; and carefully arrange the SpeedButton over the Panel. Then you might change the Panel Color property and it will appear like Button's color has changed. There is some change in functionality, as SpeedButtons can't get Focus; this may prevent its usage for you or might be a premium indeed, test and decide.

Comment: This button looks weird compared to other buttons on the form when I'm using a VCL style which rounds buttons but not panels.